# how to get client ip address in socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

hi i have issue with getting client ip address in socket.io version 1.3.7 before update its work perfect but after update i get every time undefined this is my code which is i use before update

this is my code for server side

```
sockets.on('connection',function(sock){

var address = sock.handshake.address;
```

this from client side to send ip address

```
var remote = 'http://my_ip_address:9008/';
    socket = io.connect(!!local ? local : remote);
    socket.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("connected");
            getData();
    });
```

after update its not work in socket.io version 1.3.7 so please help me with this issue and suggest perfect code for 1.3.7 version

Comment: `sock.handshake.address` should be the IP address of the client.  It works for me in socket.io 1.4.5.  It may show in an IPv6 format depending upon your system configuration.

Comment: id there any change for connection in client side for new version of socket.io , my code for client side connect socket is perfect or not if you have any idea about that so please tell me still i cant get ip address

Comment: From the server, here's how you retrieve various IP address stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423930/how-to-retrieve-client-and-server-ip-address-and-port-number-in-node-js/38426473?noredirect=1#comment64286103_38426473

Answer (score 5):

I am not much into sockets but I guess this will help you.

You need to use *`address.address`* and for port *`address.port`*

```
sockets.on('connection',function(sock){ 
var address = sock.handshake.address;
      console.log('New connection from ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
});
```

And for Socket.io ver 1.0
**Server-side :**

```
sockets.on('connection',function(sock){ 
    var clientIpAddress = sock.request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || sock.request.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.log(' new request from : '+clientIpAddress);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton - spent too much time searching for the server-side solution

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it, as of Feb 20th, 2019:

```
let ip = _.has(socket.handshake.address, 'address') 
              ? socket.handshake.address.address 
              : socket.handshake.address;
if (ip === "127.0.0.1") {
  ip = _.has(socket.handshake.headers, 'x-real-ip') 
            ? socket.handshake.headers['x-real-ip'] 
            : socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
}
```

*with the help of `lodash`'s [`.has()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#has)*